# how to color radgrid view columns programatically depending the odd and even

Tags: radgridview

how can i programatically assign the color to Rad Grid view sucn that odd number columns get one color and even number coloumns get another color any idea any one please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        if (item.ItemIndex % 2 == 0)
        {
            item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```